# How to create subfolder on mailbox trough Dovecot

Tags: centos, postfix, dovecot

On a CentOS 7 machine running Postfix and Dovecot how would one create subfolder named 'Bulk' in a inbox? Like 'INBOX.Bulk'.

I thought to use the maildirmake command but this returns "maildirmake command not found". After some digging it seems maildirmake is not available on RHEL systems. So how do I create a subfolder for an already existing mailbox?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dovecot is an IMAP server, one would normally use an IMAP client to create folders. This would work regardless of what storage backend Dovecot uses.

Dovecot also comes with the `doveadm` tool which can manage folders i.e. "mailboxes":

```
doveadm mailbox create INBOX.Bulk
```

But if you need to do it manually, to create a Maildir folder use `mkdir` to create both the base directory and the three subdirectories `cur`, `new`, `tmp` that a Maildir folder needs.

For example, if your mail root is at `~/Mail`, you can create a folder using:

```
mkdir -m 0700 ~/Mail/.INBOX.Bulk
mkdir -m 0700 ~/Mail/.INBOX.Bulk/{cur,new,tmp}
```

Though creating subfolders under INBOX is mainly Courier imapd's thing – with Dovecot there's no need to do that; you can just as well create a folder named `Bulk` directly.

```
mkdir -m 0700 ~/Mail/.Bulk
mkdir -m 0700 ~/Mail/.Bulk/{cur,new,tmp}
```

Comment: The doveadm tool is perfect and a perfect solution for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Using user1686 input, I created a simple shell script that you can just copy and paste.  I'm also using Debian 11 for the information provided.

doveadm mailbox create doesn't work for me because of some error I could not track down "doveadm(root): Error: Couldn't drop privileges: User is missing UID (see mail_uid setting)" *So, the best method is manually making directories for me.  Thanks to user1686 for that information!*

Open up your favorite editor and don't forget to give it executable permissions.  You may have to change ~/Mail to what ever your mail box directory is.... I use ~/Maildir in mine.

You can find your mail directory for dovecot in

```
/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-mail.conf
```

You'll find the variable looks like:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
```

If your root and want to change to another user, type su - username where you replace the username with the users name.

If your sudo and want to change to another user, type sudo su - username where you replace the username with the users name.

To exit the user, type exit

For each user you'll have to create a mailbox.  I didn't create a script to run thru all the users.  But I'm sure it can be done.

change users as root

```
su - username
```

change users as sudo

```
sudo - username
```

change mailbox directory for user:

```
cd ~/Maildir
```

if you don't have nano, you can get it by typing:

```
apt-get install nano
```

Open your editor

```
nano makemaildir.sh
```

Exit user

```
exit
```

Copy and paste the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Making mailbox directory $1
mkdir -m 0700 ~/Mail/.$1
mkdir -m 0700 ~/Mail/.$1/{cur,new,tmp}
```

Don't forget to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x makemaildir.sh
```

You can run it like:

```
./makemaildir.sh mymailbox
```